# SQL Adding and Subtracting Data From Two Different Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I am new in SQL, and this is my first SQL program ever my life. I want to make a program that has the following:

1. A table that has the record of number of loads that a customer delivered in a week, the rate(fee) for each load to deliver, the dispatch fee.
2. Another table that holds expenses, such us Fuel, Insurance, Trailer rent, etc.
3. I need to get the total sum of all expenses of a customer, and sum of all rates (earned money for each load), and then subtract the total expenses from the total net pays for each customer.

Note:

```
QuickPay= Rate*0.05
NetPay=Rate-(DispatchFee+QuickPay),
TotalExpenses= Fuel+Advance+Insurance+Trailer
FinalPay=NetPay-TotalExpenses
```

I have created one query for each table, to make the calculation, but I need to combine all in one query. Here is the code for the queries:

Query For TblLInfo

```
SELECT CustName, sum(Rate) AS RateFee, sum(Disp_Fee) AS DispFee, sum(Rate*0.05) AS QuickPay, sum((Rate)-((Rate*0.05)+(Disp_Fee))) AS NetPay
FROM TblLInfo
GROUP BY CustName;
```

Query For TblExp

```
SELECT CustName, sum(Fuel) AS FuelFee, sum(Advance) AS AdvanceFee, sum(Insurance) AS InsuranceFee, sum(Trailer) AS TrailerFee, 
sum((Advance)+(Insurance)+(Trailer)+(Fuel)) AS TotalExp
FROM TblExp
GROUP BY CustName;
```

When I tried to combine them, the result is 9 (3*3), records as I expected only 3 records.

[TblLInfo,(Table Load Info), For collecting weekly loads transported one customer][1]

[TblExp (Table Expenses), For collecting weekly expenses for each customer][2]

[Query For TblLInfo, to get the sum of all loads carried specific customer and subtract the dispatch fee, so we can get the net pay][3]

[Query for TblExp, to get total expenses for specific customer][4]

![enter image description here][1]

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.CustName,a.NetPay,b.TotalExp,(b.TotalExp-a.NetPay) AS overall_profit 
FROM
(SELECT CustName, sum(Rate) AS RateFee, sum(Disp_Fee) AS DispFee, sum(Rate*0.05) AS QuickPay, sum((Rate)-((Rate*0.05)+(Disp_Fee))) AS NetPay FROM TblLInfo GROUP BY CustName) a 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT CustName, sum(Fuel) AS FuelFee, sum(Advance) AS AdvanceFee, sum(Insurance) AS InsuranceFee, sum(Trailer) AS TrailerFee, sum((Advance)+(Insurance)+(Trailer)+(Fuel)) AS TotalExp FROM TblExp GROUP BY CustName)b
```

Comment: It giving me, Syntax error in FORM clause. 
But Thanks

Comment: I combined the two queries I have created as follows:

SELECT TblCusReg.Cust_ID, TblCusReg.Cust_Name, SqlQLoadInfo.WeekOf, SqlQLoadInfo.Rate, 
SqlQLoadInfo.DispFee, SqlQLoadInfo.QuickPay, SqlQLoadInfo.NetPay, SqlQExp.FuelFee,
 SqlQExp.AdvanceFee, SqlQExp.InsuranceFee, SqlQExp.TrailerFee, SqlQExp.TotalExp, [NetPay]-[TotalExp] AS FinalPay
FROM (TblCusReg INNER JOIN SqlQExp ON TblCusReg.Cust_ID = SqlQExp.CustName) INNER JOIN SqlQLoadInfo ON TblCusReg.Cust_ID = SqlQLoadInfo.CustName;

and it finally worked